# How can I wrap this INDEX function with a SEARCH function?

Tags: excel

I would like to wrap;

```
=IFERROR(INDEX(Table2,SEQUENCE(O1,ROWS(O1)),{1,4,8,17,2,10,5,7}),"")
```

in a SEARCH function so it will return only the rows with matching text from a column using a cell I point to. The cell I point to could be a list, as I change the list the rows update upon SEARCH match.

Thank you.

Comment: Put some sample data here.

Comment: I ended up wrapping it in a filter that points to the INDEX SEQUENCE function and does what I want.

=IFERROR(FILTER(A:H,ISNUMBER(SEARCH(A2,B:B))),"")

I'd still like to know if it's possible to get that output with original function.

I'm not sure how to input some sample data here. I can condense the selection columns to return.

=IFERROR(INDEX(Table2,SEQUENCE(O1,ROWS(O1)),{1,4,8}),"")

So INDEX the table, only return columns 1,4,8 based on row count that I have in O1 - could be X number of rows.